# Поиск уникальных строк в текстовом файле

Tags: java, парсер

Есть текстовый файл на вход в нем строки выгруженные с сайта, выглядят так:

> 2221214981    2221214981  Находится в стадии ликвидации   2017-06-19T00:00:00
>
> 7814249543    7814249543  Принято решение о предстоящем исключении недействующего юридического лица из ЕГРЮЛ от 01.09.2017 № 30186. Опубликовано в журнале «Вестник государственной регистрации» от 06.09.2017 № 35   2017-09-01T00:00:00
>
> 2539045051    2539045051  Находится в процессе реорганизации в форме присоединения к другому ЮЛ   2016-11-30T00:00:00

там четыре колонки, колонки разбиты табуляцией, первые две идентичны для моей же проверки, это список инн по которым я хотел выгрузить и инн который выгрузился после обращения к сайту. Потом идет некий текст. Следом идет дата.

Мне нужно вытащить уникальные текстовые строки для их дальнейшего анализа (из третьей колонки).

Знаю как сделать это через запросы к базе. Но хочу сделать это на java.

Как это можно сделать или куда смотреть чтобы это понять?

Comment: В сторону регэспов. Парсить можно через JSOUP

Comment: Парсить __не нужно__ регэкспами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя Java 8 и Stream API можно сделать следующим образом:

```java
Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"))  // читаем файл по строкам
    .map(s -> s.split("\t")[2])              // делим по табулятору и берём третий "столбец"
    .distinct()                              // оставляем только уникальные значения
    .forEach(System.out::println);           // выводим результат
```

Для того, чтобы записать результат в файл, можно написать так:

```java
// Читаем уникальные строки
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"))
    .map(s -> s.split("\t")[2]).distinct();

// Записываем в новый файл
Files.write(Paths.get("/path/to/result.txt"), (Iterable<String>) lines::iterator);
```

Comment: не совсем понятно что идет до точек. Может у меня нет какой-то библиотеки?

Comment: @Uhntiss это одна строка кода, перенесённая по точкам. Если у вас Java 8 или выше - всё должно быть.

Comment: @Uhntiss знакомьтесь, это [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java).

Comment: Спасибо! все вышло! Как корректнее записать результат в фаил? Если я напишу таким образом .forEach(Files.write(Paths.get("/my/new/file/path.txt"), lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

Comment: @Uhntiss дополнил ответ описанием, как записать в файл

Comment: @AlexChermenin В основном в этом файле присутствует одна строка, но у нее разный хеш так как в ней разные постановления и даты, как отфильтровать данные строки по начальному содержанию символов в строке?

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска уникальных строк воспользуйтесь классом [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). При добавлении элемента вычисляется его хеш и если такой элемент в коллекции есть то он не добавляется.

Например:

```
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>();
unique.add("Monday");
unique.add("Friday");
unique.add("Monday");
unique.add("Sunday");
unique.add("Sunday");
for (String s : unique) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Даст в результате:

```
Monday
Friday
Sunday
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> uniq = new HashSet<String>;

for(int i = 0; i < inputStringArray.length(); i++){
    uniq.add(inputStringArray[i].split("\\t")[3]);
}
```